How can I raise up a shed install on an existing foundation that is prone to water pooling on it?
I live in the PNW which means we get a lot of rain; there's an existing concrete slab on the side of the house (not sure why), but I was planning on building a shed on it. It has about an inch between the slab and the house foundation, and the slab is roughly 8x16.
However, it is on a hill and the slab itself is not graded, so water just sits on it when it rains. Worse, the location is basically an area where it gets literally no sunlight (and I do mean zero), so the water takes a while to dry. Seeing as building a shed floor right on the concrete would likely lead to it sitting in water, I'd be worried about even pressure treated lumber.
If I wanted to raise this shed up to allow drainage underneath it, what are my options?

If you are putting a shed on it, what are your plans for getting rid of the water around the pad since it is so close to the house?

A shed/building usually means walls and a roof.   Walls/roof should usually keep water from falling on the slab and keep it dry.  If the slab is low to the ground, you will want to add drainage and/or raise/add to the height to the slab.

Consider renting a concrete saw to cut some drainage channels. But as for "raising up a shed" if the shed will have a floor that is not the slab itself, it's pretty much a matter of setting a bunch of bricks or concrete blocks on the slab and setting the shed floor framing on top of the bricks or blocks.
Or, form and pour a new concrete slab on top of the old at a higher level and with a nice slope to be the new concrete floor of the shed.
Put pressure treated lumber between any concrete/masonry and any non-treated lumber.
If you are smarter than the average skunk you'll also put stainless steel or galvanized mesh between the shed and the slab so as not to create attractive habitat for neighbors you might not want to be that neighborly with.

If I build it up on bricks, can I basically treat it like a deck (I.e., using deck bricks)? How do I secure the bricks et al?

I wonder if the problem is that the surrounding grade tends to drain towards the shed.  Putting the shed on bricks won't really solve that problem (unless the whole slab is covered in bricks, and then you still have the water sitting there til it drains out or evaporates).  @AndrewM. can you grade the adjacent yard to drain away from the slab?  Or can you build a french drain around it—do you have a way to daylight one?

Honestly, I'm okay with the water sitting on the slab (should I be?) but I'm more concerned about wood potentially sitting there. If I use deck stones, these are only every foot or so to hold the frame, which means there should be airflow--which I'm assuming should be more than enough. My concern is more attaching it to the slab, since it looks like many of the deck stones don't really have this option.
French drain would be very difficult--it's all stones, and within 12 inches down it's boulders; it would be an endeavor for sure.

You can mortar the brick/blocks deck support things in place - but you don't need to (though it can help to correct for the slab not being level) because once you get even part of the shed framing on them, gravity will hold them in place just fine. If you expect serious wind-load uplift, tie from the roof framing all the way to anchor bolts drilled into the slab.
